# CDs with setup.exe randomly throw "The program is too big to fit in memory" error

Tags: compact-disc, autorun

I created 100 CDs, each with one `setup.exe` file that automatically runs upon insertion.

With some of the CDs, when I explore the contents of the CD, the icon of the `setup.exe` file becomes that of the command prompt and running it gives me the following error:

`The program is too big to fit in memory`

This problem appears to be random: if I take an "afflicted" CD out of the first computer and put it into another, it autoruns as expected. If I then reset the first computer, it too works properly. But, putting it into yet another computer results in the same issue.

I am certain that malware is not causing this, as I am checking with different PCs and with fully updated definitions.

What is going on? And how can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

What program? What OS? How big is your hard drive? How much RAM do you have?

My general shot-in-the-dark assumption is you either have too little RAM, or your hard drive doesn't have enough space. If its a virus its a very strange one that I've never seen before.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error when trying to run programs compiled for 64-bit Windows in a 32-bit Windows environment.

I'm not sure what tools exist to check whether an executable is 32-bit or 64-bit, but maybe you could try running the setup on a 64-bit Windows box.